# Functions not executing before Sys.sleep()

Tags: r, system

I am writing a function that needs to catch a rate-limiting error while pinging a web-based API.

I am using `tryCatch` to catch the error, and inside this function I specify the following error function:

```
error=function(e) {
                warning(paste(e,"\nWaiting an hour for rate limit to reset..."))
                Sys.sleep(3600) # Wait an hour for rate-limit to reset
                return(user.info(user, ego.count))
            }
```

The function appears to work, but when checking the output logs for the script I notice that the warning message is not written until **after** the sleep time has run out.

I can reproduce this behavior at the R console with:

```
print("Drew sucks")
Sys.sleep(10)
```

Ten seconds pass before `Drew sucks` is printed to the console.  In my function, I would like to provide some feedback to the user about this long pause before the pause happens.

What is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the hell of it, try:

```
system(sprintf('sleep %d', seconds))
```

Assuming you've got the usual *NIX sleep command on path.

Comment: One thing - if one uses `warning` then user can use `suppressWarnings` to not show messages. With this solution another way is needed.

Answer (score 8):

You need to either set `immediate.=TRUE`  to your warning function, or set `options(warn=1)`; and *may* need to add `flush.console()` (on some operating systems) before the `Sys.sleep()` call.

```
foo <- function() {
  warning("uh-oh...", immediate.=TRUE)
  flush.console()
  Sys.sleep(5)
  "done"
}
foo()
# Warning in foo() : uh-oh...
# [1] "done"
```

The specifics are spelled out in the "Details" section of `?warning`.  To paraphrase, *"if options(warn=0), warnings are stored and printed after the top-level function has completed; if options(warn=1) they are printed as they occur."*

Comment: It may be a an OS issue, but on OS X that function still executes the `Sys.sleep` call before printing the warning.

Comment: It works for me on Windows and Ubuntu (and Ubuntu doesn't need `flush.console()`).

Comment: @DrewConway  It works for me on OSX running via the terminal.  Are you in the GUI?  (or more specifically - which one, if so)

Comment: Drew, I think you do have something screwy going on - there's no reason that the print() should be delayed by the sleep if they're both running from the command prompt.  I just tried it on my Mac and am still not seeing that behavior.

Comment: I think @Jeff R is onto it. I get the expected behavior if I run R or R64 from the command line. I get the incorrect behavior you report when using the normal Mac R GUI. RStudio works as expected. There must be some buffering between R and the GUI which flush.console() doesn't fix.

Comment: It also works as expected from eclipse via the StatET plugin on OS X.

Answer (score 3):

By default, warnings aren't printed immediately, instead they are printed out after the top level function returns.  You can set warn to '1' if you want it to print out immediately, and even higher if you want it to stop

Comment: Hmm, after re-reading your post, I'm not sure I actually am answering the right question.  I thought you were saying that you want the warning() to print out immediately when it's called, is that right?

Comment: I do, but the issue does not appear to only apply to `warning` calls, as with my `print` example.

Comment: That's what made me think I might not be grokking your question.  If I start up R and run your print example, I get the output of the print and then the delay.  If doing the same thing for you really doesn't perform the print() before the Sys.sleep(), something else is going on (e.g. Hadley's answer).

I do think you're going to run into issues w/ the warning() being in a function either way though.

Answer (score 2):

Probably related to output buffering - see `?flush.console`

Comment: On the other hand, console i/o never is buffered. r might be an exception, but that would be a surprise, wouldn't it? Yet another scheme inspiration I'll want to look on (doh)...

Comment: Adding `flush.console()` did not fix the problem in the "Drew sucks" example from above.